# Azure Function Runtime version: 2.0.11888.0 (beta) become connot able to connect to cosmosDB

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing the simple node.js code for inserting of new document to cosmosDB via Azure function app by using http trigger function. That's simply get the input value from http's parameter and output to cosmosDB(SQL api). About last 2 weeks, it was successfully running but now facing with internal server error. That's why? Is is affect on azure function's runtime minor version update?

->function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "ToDoList",
      "collectionName": "Items",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

->index.js

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

    context.bindings.outputDocument = JSON.stringify({ 
        name: req.query.name
    });

    context.done();
};
```

->browsing error
`INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

Answer (score 1):

You are right, function runtime update(begin with `2.0.11857`) has a breaking change for JavaScript functions. See this [issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/112#issuecomment-397104778).

> We are deprecating support for Node v6, which may affect deployed function apps. Please change WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION in App Settings to an 8.x version that is >=8.4.0 (for example: 8.11.1).

Have done some tests, it does cause Internal Server Error if I keep `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` as `6.5.0`.

Before `2.0.11857` releases, `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is `6.5.0` in both v1 and v2 function. After then, when we upgrade function runtime from ~1 to beta, `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` changes to `8.11.1` automatically.

**Update**

Node version changing doesn't work for you, maybe it's cased by cosmosdb extension being broken. You could have a try while I can't reproduce your problem on my side.

Steps to reinstall extension:

1. Stop your function app.
2. Visit `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.
3. Delete the folder `bin` and `extension.csproj`.
4. Go back to function portal and create a cosmosdb trigger to install the extension again.
5. Start your function app to test.

Comment: Hello....did you mean you had being connected to cosmosDB just align on the node.js version? But, I cannot. ;(

Comment: @KhinThet Yes, with node version set to `8.11.1`, I can connect  to cosmosDB and output document. Could you restart you function app and try again?

Comment: Yes, I did restart. But not yet success. Anyway, my app runtime was 2.0.11888.

Comment: @KhinThet Your function seems broken somewhere else. Have you got any detailed error info in your logs? If it's acceptable, you can try to create a new function app to test.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I always try this process at least one time a day, but it's still not success for me. I was used azure logic apps that's simple instance of azure function app now. If I possible, also wanna success with azure function app.

Comment: @KhinThet you could try to reinstall your cosmosdb extension, see my update.